# django-auth-ldap - Display user information from LDAP in custom view

Tags: python, django, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I'm using django-auth-ldap with following setting because there is no default/global 'admin' user on the ldap server, its only for authenticating users and users themselves may see their user information.

```
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_AS_AUTHENTICATING_USER=True
```

in `django-ldap-debug.log` i get following error when (as logged in user) calling in view `LDAPBackend().populate_user(request.user.username)`

```
search_s('uid=vchrizz,ou=Users,dc=funkfeuer,dc=at', 0, '(objectClass=*)') raised NO_SUCH_OBJECT({'desc': 'No such object'},)
search_s('uid=vchrizz,ou=Users,dc=funkfeuer,dc=at', 0, '(objectClass=*)') returned 0 objects:
```

only when logging in (using `login_required` from `django.contrib.auth.decorators`) it returns a user object it seems:

```
search_s('uid=vchrizz,ou=Users,dc=funkfeuer,dc=at', 0, '(objectClass=*)') returned 1 objects: uid=vchrizz,ou=users,dc=funkfeuer,dc=at
```

then i noticed, i need to set

```
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD
```

to get rid of the error, but first i dont want to specify a user with password (cause `bind_as_authenticating_user`) and second populate_user() still returns `NoneType` ...

why? how do i get the returned user information from ldap?

my goal is to display all ldap user information like uidNumber from the ldap-user in my custom /userinfo/ view.
http://pastebin.com/VqGiwzFE

thanks, chris

Comment: what i forgot to make it work:
`user = auth.authenticate(username="theuser", password="thepass")`
naturally i dont want hardcoded user credentials here, so i can replace "theuser" with  `request.user.username` but not the password as `request.user.password` is the hashed password.

as the password is in /login/ view in POST, i guess its better to get the (authenticated) user object from /login/ view into /userinfo/ view? but how do i do that?

Comment: from [Django-AttributeError 'User' object has no attribute 'backend' (But…it does?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034763/django-attributeerror-user-object-has-no-attribute-backend-but-it-does) ive read that auth.authenticate() is needed, and i guess i need this: [Re: Modify authentication backend](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-auth-ldap/9D_VJYI0L9U) to somehow get the user object from login view to userinfo view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the end `auth.authenticate` was missing and i had to rtfm:

[Storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)
this is the preferred way to get user information instead the way i was looking for.

settings.py:

```
AUTH_LDAP_PROFILE_ATTR_MAP = {
    "uid": "uid",
    "cn": "cn",
    "sn": "sn",
    "givenName": "givenName",
    "userPassword": "userPassword",
    "shadowLastChange": "shadowLastChange",
    "shadowMax": "shadowMax",
    "shadowWarning": "shadowWarning",
    "loginShell": "loginShell",
    "uidNumber": "uidNumber",
    "gidNumber": "gidNumber",
    "homeDirectory": "homeDirectory",
    "gecos": "gecos",
    "mail": "mail",
    "l": "l",
    "telephoneNumber": "telephoneNumber",
}
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myapp.UserProfile'
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # Other fields here
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    cn = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    sn = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    givenName = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    userPassword = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    shadowLastChange = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    shadowMax = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    shadowWarning = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    loginShell = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    uidNumber = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    gidNumber = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    homeDirectory = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    gecos = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    mail = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    l = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    telephoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=254)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    #if created:
    #    UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.models import UserProfile

@login_required
def userinfo(request):
    try:
        ldapuserprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(uid=request.user.username)
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    context = {'request': request, 'ldapuser': ldapuserprofile,}
    return render(request, 'myapp/userinfo.html', context)
```

then in html template its possible to access `{{ ldapuser.givenName }}`

maybe it helps someone.

thanks, chris