# multiple authentication backends configured and therefore must provide the `backend` argument or set the `backend` attribute on the user

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ubuntu, oauth

first of i am new to `django/python` .

i am trying to create a login website that allows the user to register an `account` and `verify` via `email` or directly `login` via `fb` or `google`(`Oauth`)

i receive the error when i click on the validation url sent to the `email`.

`error`:

```
ValueError at /activate/Mjk/4p1-dcc5f7ed2e7c847fe362/

You have multiple authentication backends configured and therefore must 

provide the `backend` argument or set the `backend` attribute on the user.

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/activate/Mjk/4p1-dcc5f7ed2e7c847fe362/
Django Version: 1.11.3

Exception Type: ValueError

Exception Value:    

You have multiple authentication backends configured and therefore must provide the `backend` argument or set the `backend` attribute on the user.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py in login, line 149
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/gaby/django projects/simple-signup-master/profile-model',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/gaby/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Server time:    Wed, 30 Aug 2017 12:34:31 +0000
```

## mysite/settings

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    
     'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
     'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',

     'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

## this is the function being called when i receive the error

```
    def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
    uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
    user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
    user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, 
    token):
    user.is_active = True
    user.profile.email_confirmed = True
    user.save()
    login(request, user)
    return redirect('home')
else:
    return render(request, 'account_activation_invalid.html')
```

i started receiving the `error` after adding the `oath` login via `fb`,`google`.
if i remove'`social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2`','`social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2`' from `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` the `email confirmation` will work again.

i searched online and also here the only solution that i found was below but it didn't solve my problem.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064443/django-multiple-authentication-backend-for-one-project-how)

Answer (score 51):

I found the solution. call `login()` with backend argument like `login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')`

here is full code:

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.profile.email_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request, 'account_activation_invalid.html')
```

Comment: In my case, I had to authenticate the user before calling login method.

Answer (score 12):

So in my case I simply hadn't registered the user. Also did `login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')`

To register user:

```
# register.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
cfg_user = 'user'
user = User.objects.create_user(username=cfg_user,
                                 email='email@domain.com',
                                 password='password')
print('registered user '+cfg_user)

# register.sh
python manage.py shell < register.py
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the build in django class PasswordResetConfirmView, then you can fix it by adding:

```
post_reset_login_backend = "django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend"
```

Something like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views

class PasswordResetConfirmView(views.PasswordResetConfirmView):
    template_name = "reset_confirm.html"
    success_url = "/"
    post_reset_login = True
    post_reset_login_backend = "django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set **multiple authentication backends** in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend",
]
```

You need to set `backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` to `login()` in `views.py` as shown below then the error will be solved:

```py
# "account/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import NewUserForm
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib import messages

def register_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()   # Here
            login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
            messages.success(request, "Registration successful.")
            return redirect("account:homepage")
        messages.error(request, "Unsuccessful registration. Invalid information.")
    form = NewUserForm()
    return render(request, "account/register.html", {"register_form":form})
```

In addition, when I set `backend='graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend'` to `login()` in `views.py` as shown below then the error was solved as well in my case so if you set **one of multiple authentication backends**, the error may be solved as well:

```py
# "account/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import NewUserForm
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib import messages

def register_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()   # Here
            login(request, user, backend='graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend')
            messages.success(request, "Registration successful." )
            return redirect("account:homepage")
        messages.error(request, "Unsuccessful registration. Invalid information.")
    form = NewUserForm()
    return render(request, "account/register.html", {"register_form":form})
```

And, if you set **only one `"django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend"`**
to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
]
```

Or, if you don't explicitly set `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` itself in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

# AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
#     "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
# ]
```

You don't need to set `backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` to `login()` in `views.py` because `"django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend"` is set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In my case just simple assigning some of backend class from Django configuration to user work properly:

`setattr(user, 'backend', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend')`

and then you can authenticate your user

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775268/django-1-2-session-loss/5837046#5837046) you need to set the backend of the user record. Before `login(request, user)` add the following line:

```
user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
...
login(request, user)
```